# Importing jQuery, Masonry & other libraries in GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, gatsby

Even after googling, I'm having trouble finding the best way to import/include jQuery, Masonry and some other jQuery based libraries in my GatsbyJS project using the webpack pipeline.

I can include  tags manually, but my understanding is that it's ideal to use import so it gets pipelined and packed.

```
import jQuery from '../js/jquery.min.js'
import '../js/flickr.js'
import '../js/flexslider.min.js'
import '../js/lightbox.min.js'
import '../js/masonry.min.js'
```

This always produces the error:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

from the flickr.js & masonry..min.js libraries

Comment: `import {jQuery as $} from '../js/jquery.min.js';`

Comment: have you looked at npm or yarn before?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on the excellent ReactJS doc on [How to integrate React with other libraries](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#how-to-approach-the-problem).

The idea is to attach a `ref` to an empty `<div />` and reference to it in `componentDidMount()`where you can pass it to your jQuery plugin.

#### code from the react's doc:

```
class SomePlugin extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.$el = $(this.el);
    this.$el.somePlugin();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.$el.somePlugin('destroy');
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={el => this.el = el} />;
  }
}
```